# Dynamically accessing properties using Spring 3.1's property abstraction

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to dynamically access properties from Spring's [Environment property abstraction](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/).

I declare my property files like this:

```
<context:property-placeholder
    location="classpath:server.common.properties,
    classpath:server.${my-environment}.properties" />
```

In my property file `server.test.properties`, I define the following:

```
myKey=foo
```

Then, given the following code:

```
@Component
public class PropertyTest {
    @Value("${myKey}")
    private String propertyValue;

    @Autowired 
    private PropertyResolver propertyResolver;

    public function test() {
         String fromResolver = propertyResolver.getProperty("myKey");
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I end up with `propertyValue='foo'`, but `fromResolver=null`;

Receiving `propertyValue` indicates that the properties *are* being read, (and I know this from other parts of my code).  However, attempting to look them up dynamically is failing.

Why?  How can I dynamically look up property values, without having to use `@Value`?

Comment: Why do you want to look them up dynamically by the way, that kind of defeats the purpose of IoC.

Comment: I'm trying to consume a set of properties that aren't known until runtime.  i.e., `listOfPropertiesToConsume=propA,propB`.  I then want to look up `propA`,`propB`, to process them.

Comment: Oh god, that seems like a massive workaround.

Comment: What are your alternative suggestions?

Comment: I've never used them, but possible [Profiles](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/).

Comment: Profiles provide a way to modify the properties that are loaded into the environment.  They're not a way to access the resolved property map.

Answer (score 2):

Simply adding a `<context:property-placeholder/>` doesn't add a new PropertySource to the Environment. If you read the article you linked completely, you'll see it suggests registering an `ApplicationContextInitializer` in order to add new PropertySources so they'll be available in the way you're trying to use them.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding, but I don't believe I'm trying to add a new property source -- just trying to use the ones that I've already declared.  The property I'm after gets populated via the `@Value` annotation, suggesting it's available to the context / environment -- but not via the injected `Environment` instance.

Comment: That's the point: you *haven't* "declared" a PropertySource. You've configured property placeholders to be replaced based on values loaded from some properties files. That's not a PropertySource. Read the article again. By default, there are two PropertySources: one that has system properties and one that has environment variables. You have to add another PropertySource to the Environment yourself if you want to be able to resolve properties in that way. The article implies it can only be done programmatically. I don't know if that's the case, but I'm not aware of any other way, either.

Comment: Maybe this is the disconnect: the `PropertyResolver` can only resolve properties that are available in registered PropertySources. Unless you register a PropertySource containing your `myKey` property, you won't be able to resolve it in that way.

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work I had to split out the reading of the properties into a `@Configuration` bean, as [shown here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html).

Here's the complete example:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/server.${env}.properties")
public class AngularEnvironmentModuleConfiguration  {

    private static final String PROPERTY_LIST_NAME = "angular.environment.properties";

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean(name="angularEnvironmentProperties")
    public Map<String,String> getAngularEnvironmentProperties()
    {
        String propertiesToInclude = environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_LIST_NAME, "");
        String[] propertyNames = StringUtils.split(propertiesToInclude, ",");

        Map<String,String> properties = Maps.newHashMap();
        for (String propertyName : propertyNames)
        {
            String propertyValue = environment.getProperty(propertyName);
            properties.put(propertyName, propertyValue);
        }

        return properties;
    }
}
```

The set of properties are then injected elsewhere, to be consumed.

Comment: It looks like you found what I just found: the `@PropertySource` annotation for registering a new PropertySource via annotation. I don't get what that whole `getAngularEnvironmentProperties()` method is about, though. All you should need is the annotation to make your previous code work as expected.